# Solr indexing with basic authentication

Tags: solr, basic-authentication, apache-tika

Solr urldatasource does not have support for username and password. I want to access my data from SNOW server that has a basic authentication.How to do it?

I have tried http://username:password@domain.com. but this does not work
I have read somewhere about tika but unable to find good documentaion for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a patch available [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1490) for this purpose. It is probably outdated but you could port it to a newer version.

Or, as a second option, you can use java (or groovy or whatever) code and SorlJ api to get your data from the datasource and index it. If your scenario involves a lot of corner cases that would be the easiest in the end.

Comment: I have already applied that patch. but it fails with the latest version. Second option- this option is not valid due to performance issue,It is kind of bypassing the request.